# MKMapView frame inside UIView not getting changed

Tags: ios7, mapkit

I have a Class of type UIView with xib. I have added MKMapView on xib. I am adding this class view on my controller class. But the size of the MKMapView is not getting changed.

Can someone help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know weather it is a right approach or not. But it solved my problem. In order to have two map views of different sizes , i created two xibs of different sizes.

Hope it helps.